# MS Word: How to display page numbers on inserted blank pages?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using "Section Break (Odd Page)" to get every chapter of a document in Microsoft Word to start on an odd page number. I'm also displaying the page number at the bottom of the page. When I save the document as PDF, the page numbers are not displayed on the blank pages inserted due to the "Section Break (Odd Page)". How can I make Word display page numbers on the inserted blank pages?

I'm using Office365 on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your section ends on an odd page, and you want a numbered (but otherwise blank) even page to follow, insert a page break at the end of the odd page. This page break is in addition to your section break.

[image: Page break and Odd page section break]

If you ever add/remove content, so that the section that used to end on an odd page now ends on an even page, you'll need to delete the page break, keeping just the section break. Otherwise, you'll end up with 2 extraneous pages (one of which has just a page number and the other of which is completely blank).